# Can systems of equations of diagonal quadratic forms be solved by Gaussian Elimination

Tags: quadratic-forms

Can the following system of equations be solved using Gaussian Elimination?

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        s_{00} & s_{01} & s_{02} & s_{03}\\
        s_{10} & s_{11} & s_{12} & s_{13}\\
        s_{20} & s_{21} & s_{22} & s_{23}\\
        s_{30} & s_{31} & s_{32} & s_{33}\\
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        x^2_0 \\
        x^2_1 \\
        x^2_2 \\
        x^2_3
        \end{bmatrix} =
        \begin{bmatrix}
         1 \\
         1 \\
         1 \\
         1
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
x_{i} \in \mathbb{R}, s_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}, 0 \leq i \leq 3, 0 \leq j \leq 3
$$

If one were to let $$w_i = x^2_i, 0 \leq i \leq 3,$$ then the above system is (trivially) transformed to

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        s_{00} & s_{01} & s_{02} & s_{03}\\
        s_{10} & s_{11} & s_{12} & s_{13}\\
        s_{20} & s_{21} & s_{22} & s_{23}\\
        s_{30} & s_{31} & s_{32} & s_{33}\\
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        w_0 \\
        w_1 \\
        w_2 \\
        w_3
        \end{bmatrix} =
        \begin{bmatrix}
         1 \\
         1 \\
         1 \\
         1
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

which CAN be solved via Gaussian Elimination. Now assuming that

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        w'_0 \\
        w'_1 \\
        w'_2 \\
        w'_3
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

is a unique solution to the above system does that mean that

$$x_i = \pm\sqrt{w'_i}$$

is the zero-dimensional solution set for the original system? Clearly this is only the case when $$w'_i \geq 0$$.

I did try to find articles dealing with systems of quadratic forms that have a diagonal Matrix but I could not find anything relevant.

If the above approach is wrong can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance